# gdb: get address of strings/comments

Tags: string, gdb, comments

Is it possible to get the address of strings from a program that is compiled with debug info?

e.g.,:

```
int main(void)
{
     // Call function
     f();
     return 0; 
}
```

Is it possible to get the address of the string "// Call function" ? 
If I use "info line x" I do get an address but it does not contain the string. It contains instructions for calling f();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to get the address of the string "// Call function" ?

No, because that string is *not* in the compiled program.

The very first step in the compilation process is preprocessing, which expands all macro definitions, *and strips all comments*.

You can see the output of that step by running

```
gcc -E t.c
```

Your comment will *not* be there.

It's possible to ask gcc to leave comments in preprocessed source (with the `-C` flag), but it is not possible to "compile" comments into the final binary.